# UITableView - reloadData from separate class

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, uipopovercontroller, reloaddata

I searched and looked over many similar questions, yet still cannot find the answer.
How do I reference a different class without initializing another instance of it?
How do I call "reloadData" from a separate class to reflect the MOC's data.
The MOC seems to be saving as I have verified it by NSNotification.

Popover Class:

```
-(void)actionSave:(id)sender {
     MainContent *entityContent =
         [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MainContent"
              inManagedObjectContext:self.mDoc.managedObjectContext];
     entityContent.date = [NSDate date];
     entityContent.title = self.titleName.text;

     //Main Question: How do I call the ViewController's function that is in a separate class?
     [ViewController reloadTableView]; //???

     //Separate Question: How do I dismiss this popover from inside of this function?
}
```

ViewController Class:

```
-(void)setupTable {
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(gridV1, 140, column1_width, 768-170) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    self.tableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    self.tableView.delegate = self.tableViewController;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self.tableViewController;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
-(void)reloadTableView{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

TableViewController Class: (self.tableView's delegate and datasource)

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MainContent"];

    // I want to sort them by the "date" attribute input by [NSDate date].
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];

    // no predicate because we want ALL of the data in the "MainContent" entity.

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request                                                                
        managedObjectContext:self.mDoc.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
}
- (void)setMDoc:(UIManagedDocument *)mDoc {
    if (_mDoc != mDoc) _mDoc = mDoc;
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (!self.mDoc) {
        [[globalMDoc sharedDocumentHandler] performWithDocument:^(UIManagedDocument *coreDatabase) {
            self.mDoc = coreDatabase;
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
        }];
    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Overview Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    MainContent *content = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = content.title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [content date]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Use a singleton, that way it wouldn't get init'ed twice.

Comment: I'm having a hard time converting the UITableView into a singleton, the initWithFrame function is lost... Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: How do I delegate and datasource the TableViewController to this singleton? Subclass it as a child class...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so make a singleton like the example from this link: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Then make an ivar in the Singleton for your UIViewController that your UITableView is in. Then in the VDL of the UITableView view, do something like

`[Singleton sharedSingleton].theViewController = self;`

Then in the other view do something like

```
    Singleton *singleton = [Singleton sharedSingleton];
    [singleton.mytableview reloadData];
```

However, for the (= self) line, you may want to do it somewhere earlier like the applicationDidFinishLaunching so that the theViewController variable is not nil when you try to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use NSNotifcations, I have a couple of events that occur asynchronously, and I post a notification back.

That is, what I do is download a picture on a background thread, and reload the table once it finishes. I do this by sending a notification to the tableviewclass, and the table view class reloads its own tableview.

~ Dan